# Elastic beanstalk amazon linux 2 docker support dockerrun.aws.json file?

Tags: docker, amazon-ebs

My application is based on elastic beanstalk multi-container docker and I want to upgrade it to amazon linux 2 docker.

What is the process to update it

Answer (score 0):

Below here I will explain how I handled the migration from multi-container docker to amazon linux 2, i'll also include the yaml file for github if interested. Also, dont forget to attach correct policys to your IAM role as well for this to work (ECR & ELB permissions).

What I did was to basically create a new app on elastic beanstalk and ***specify the Amazon Linux 2 platform under Docker as deployement option.***

When the new server was up and running with the latest code, I then changed my app URL from my domain provider with a MX record to the new app url from ELB.

Below I will attach my docker-compose.yaml file and also the Github workflow with the part of deploying to ELB if you are interested (Or if it might help someone else)

Docker-compose.yaml, you will need to either remove the image or insert your own image tag url.

```
version: '3'
services:
  node-app:
    image: <IMG-TAG here e.g from ECR repository>
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

github.yaml

```
  deploy-staging:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Generate deployment package
        run: |
          zip -r deploy.zip *
      - name: Deploy to EB
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v9
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          application_name: test
          environment_name: test
          version_label: ${{ github.sha }}
          region: eu-north-1
          deployment_package: deploy.zip
          use_existing_version_if_available: true
```